# linear algebra, given the dimension of the kernel of the transformation and finding k.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If the dimension of the kernel of the transformation
$$T \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3,\ T((x, y, z)) = (2x + y, x + z, kx + 2y - z)$$
is $1$, find $k$.

I found,
$\operatorname{kernel} = \{1,-2,-1\}$
and $k$ is $3$.

is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, except that $\ker T$ is not $(1,-2,-1)$; it is spanned by it.

The determinant of the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis of $\Bbb R^3$ is $k-3$, and therefore $3$ is the only value that $k$ can take for which $\ker T\ne\{0\}$. And it is easy to check that, for this value of $k$, $\ker T$ is spanned by $(1,-2,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel is span$\{(1,-2,-1)\}$ not just the vector $(1,-2,-1)$.